# I want to check "Sec-WebSocket-Accept" in client side

Tags: html, websocket, handshake

I'm making a C server of websocket :D
actually one time I did connect successfully but after then,
this onOpen is not triggering again...and tells me

```
Error during WebSocket handshake: Sec-WebSocket-Accept mismatch
```

so now I need to check what client HTML takes especially the `Sec-WebSocket-Accept` field

Is there a way I can check `Sec-WebSocket-Accept` field in javascript client side?
What value should I check for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Sec-WebSocket-Accept header expected to be sent by a WebSocket server during the initial opening handshake cannot be accessed from JavaScript (in browsers).

You can however look at the complete opening handshake i.e. in the developer console of Chrome, *after* the handshake has succeeded.

The value must be computed by the server based on the Sec-WebSocket-Key sent by the client (and a magic string). You can read the details in https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455

Comment: really thank you for respond!!! it's so helpful to me and now I'm done to make C server!!! although it can handshake only^^; now I'm studying dataframing looks harder than handshake;;;

Comment: Viewing the handshake and (particularly) message reads in the Chrome console would be very useful.  Can you tell me where to look for them please?  I can't see anything in the console tab; should I look under a different tab?

Comment: You can view data from the WS opening handshake like so (in Chrome):

F12 -> network tab -> reload page -> websocket subtab (bottom) -> click on path (left pane).

You cannot (to my knowledge) automatically "wiretap" WS messages exchanged _after_ the handshake within Chrome.

There may be a dissector for Wireshark which could allow that.

Comment: Thanks.  Shame there isn't a way to capture all ws traffic.

Comment: sorry for being late to reply^^;